# Over current protection design

Tags: switches, circuit-design, protection

I've designed the following over-current shutdown circuits, for both positive and negative rails, with only elementary and relatively ship components. In spice simulations, they work under a wide range of voltages (simulation works for 2-40V) and current limits (0-5A range at least) but I have not tried to build them yet. The power consumption is low.
What issues can occur with these circuits?

In the following schematic (negative rail), the current limit is set to 1A, while the voltage can range from 2-40V (the picture is small, but zooming the screen works fine). When the current exceeds 1A (e.g. short circuit), the circuit shuts down until the cause of the failure is removed.

[image: negative rail design]

The next schematic is for the positive rail; same principle but a bit more complicated because I know no "high side" version of the LM393, so I've divided the compared voltages by two.

[image: positive rail design]

Comment: what happens after it's shut down, does it come on again? And if so, what happens then?

Comment: I don't understand the question. After it's shut down, it does not come again until the cause of the failure is removed. This is because there is a (sufficiently) big voltage difference at the two terminals of the comparator, since the FET is off (when the FET is on, the 10 Ohm resistor adds almost nothing to the voltage difference created by the 0.01 Ohm resistor). But if the cause of the failure is removed (Load disconnected), then this big voltage difference disappears and the circuit can operate again.